# Installing Touch Light Switch

Tags: wiring, switch, light

I'm looking to replace a light switch but the terminals are labeled differently to my existing one and i'm wondering if anyone can offer advice.

My current switch looks as follows with two wires going into a COM terminal and one into an L1 terminal:

[image]

and the switch i'm looking to install has the following terminals:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should edit into your question the model number of the new switch and/or a link to the online documentation.  (Or perhaps a photo of the wiring diagram on the paper instructions) Right now we can only guess what might work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your wiring colors (or should I say *colours*), suggest you are not in the US, so I'll preface my answer with this: **I have very little knowledge of non-US wiring standards.** It looks like the current UK wire color scheme, though, with brown as a single-phase live (240V), blue as a neutral, and the yellow/green as a ground.

That aside, you shouldn't have too much trouble with this wiring. I am not entirely sure what the terminal marked "N" and "LOOP" is for since I wouldn't expect a 3-way traveler to go to a terminal marked as a neutral. Anyway, it doesn't appear relevant anyway. I might just be for an illuminated switch.

To simply replace the current switch, you would connect the wires currently on "COM" to "L" on the new switch and the wires currently on "L1" to the new "L1."